# Is there an R Equivalent to this Python WebSocket script?

Tags: python, r, json, api, websocket

For context, I have an enterprise level subscription to an API provider which includes real-time financial data via a WebSocket protocol. However, the documentation only gives guidance on how to use the WebSocket with Python and NodeJS. I want to establish a connection to the WebSocket via R so I can stream real-time financial data, specifically using the 'websocket' library. Here is the code the API documentation provides for python users.

```
import websocket
import simplejson as json
import time
import ssl

ws = websocket.WebSocket(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})
ws.connect("wss://websockets.financialmodelingprep.com")

login = {
    'event':'login',
    'data': {
        'apiKey': "<key>",
    }
}

subscribe = {
    'event':'subscribe',
    'data': {
        'ticker': "aapl",
    }
}

unsubscribe = {
    'event':'unsubscribe',
    'data': {
        'ticker': "aapl",
    }
}

ws.send(json.dumps(login))
 
time.sleep(1)
 
ws.send(json.dumps(subscribe))
 
time.sleep(1)
 
ws.send(json.dumps(unsubscribe))

while True:
    print(ws.recv())
```

I tried to use the WebSocket$new() function in R but I keep getting errors, and I'm assuming this is because I'm not adding my credentials properly. Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
WebSocket$new(
  url = 'wss://crypto.financialmodelingprep.com/',
  headers = list(
    login = "{
      'event' = 'login',
      'data' = {'apiKey' : <key>}
    
    }"
    
  )
)
```

And here is the error I am getting:

```
<WebSocket>
  Public:
    clearAccessLogChannels: function (channels = c("all")) 
    clearErrorLogChannels: function (channels = c("all")) 
    clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
    close: function (code = 1000L, reason = "") 
    connect: function () 
    initialize: function (url, protocols = character(0), headers = NULL, autoConnect = TRUE, 
    onClose: function (callback) 
    onError: function (callback) 
    onMessage: function (callback) 
    onOpen: function (callback) 
    protocol: function () 
    readyState: function () 
    send: function (msg) 
    setAccessLogChannels: function (channels = c("all")) 
    setErrorLogChannels: function (channels = c("all")) 
  Private:
    accessLogChannels: function (channels, stompValue) 
    accessLogChannelValues: none connect disconnect control frame_header frame_paylo ...
    callbacks: environment
    errorLogChannels: function (channels, stompValue) 
    errorLogChannelValues: none devel library info warn rerror fatal all
    getInvoker: function (eventName) 
    pendingConnect: FALSE
    wsObj: externalptr
```

I've also tried following [this](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/your-first-websocket-client-in-r-85b502925a4a) tutorial but again, it doesn't help me figure out my problem.
Would anyone know how I can successfully establish this connection in R? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case that you found a solution, please post it. You can answer your own question.